# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on https://npmcdn.com/ng2-img-cropper/index.js website

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

While I was working on my app I began getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://npmcdn.com/ng2-img-cropper/index.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I was thinking about what's causing the error. I know there is a https://npmcdn.com/** url, so it's probably not in my computer, but I just wanted to be sure.

Also, I've tried accessing the site directly from the browser and everything works as it should. It gives me back the script etc. It's just weird for me because I was actually working with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on my back-end when I began getting this one, but I've tried to comment out everything and I still get it. I was considering something happened because of my .htaccess file, that I was editing too. May I know your opinion what's going on here? Is it possible my computer or connection is causing it?

**UPDATE**

The problem I have is with node_module ng2-img-cropper. I didn't want to publish it before I wasn't sure it's not an issue on my side. I found out that this node_module is using the old npmcdn.com website to load it's files. It always calls npmcdn.com which redirects it to unpkg.com. Next, if you try GET Request on npmcdn.com it redirect you to the unpkg.com and even though it gives me all the data, and headers are set, it probably checks the headers from the npmcdn.com site and says that I'm unable to catch it. Any idea how to solve this? I was thinking about changing the config in npm, so that every node_module would call unpkg.com, and not the older one npmcdn.com. But where to find this config file?

Comment: Do you have control over npmcdn.com?

Comment: there is no star in the link I just meant it like any package of any version. If I must be concrete I'm using ng2-img-cropper v.0.6.4 which should be the latest one. It worked fine today morning.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question right, but I can ping the page and also my DNS works fine. It redirects me to unpkg.com, but it's says it's node package storage website so I guess it works fine. 

And I'm getting the error just with this package, I guess I would get more errors if it was the connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only solution was not the best, but this way it worked. I copied the whole module from node_modules folder and put into my `src/app/` location. Then in component I've just imported component from it's path in my app folder and added the `/index` so it's grabbing exports from `index.ts`.

Answer (score 2):

I know npmcdn.com just moved to unpkg.com, perhaps the redirect doesn't have the header set correctly. Does pointing to unpkg.com directly work?

Comment: I'm not home right now. I'll check it then. Don't you have some website where I would find more info about that moving?

Comment: I had a map in systemjs.config.js to npmcdn.com. Changing to unpkg.com fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is saying you can't do (AJAX) request throught domains. From a domain www.site-a.com you can't do a request to www.site-b.com, because this is not the same domain. This is a Web Browser security.

If you want request www.site-b.com from www.site-a.com, so www.site-a.com has to set the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to allow other domains to request it.

If you have access to https://npmcdn.com you can configure the server, else you will not be able to request it.

Comment: Yeah well, I know what the error is saying. In my API I've got server set properly, but this is the official npm web server so... :/

Comment: As Drew Schuster said in an answer, npmcdn seems to be a redirection to unpkg. So it is possible than npmcdn does not send header. But, unpkg sends the right header. Try your Ajax request to unpkg?